# ראש וראשון לכל דבר שבקדושה

Tags: sources-mekorot, language, text

The phrase "ראש וראשון לכל דבר שבקדושה" is used quite often in *haskamos* and introductions to describe people who devote their life to Torah study or supporting Torah study or other important Jewish community institutions.

Where does this phrase come from? I can't find it in any basic Jewish text like Tanach or the Talmud Bavli. Did someone make it up, and if so, who?

Comment: Is it used only in the context of Kohanim? Because it reminds me a lot of [Moed Katan 28b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=12&daf=28b&format=pdf)

Answer (score 4):

I believe it is paraphrased from the Gemara ([Gittin 59b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=19&daf=59b&format=text))
The Gemara is discussing the honour accorded to a Kohen, saying that he is accorded ראשון  for לכל דבר שבקדושה.

וקדשתו לכל דבר שבקדושה תנא דבי רבי ישמעאל וקדשתו לכל דבר שבקדושה לפתוח ראשון ולברך ראשון וליטול מנה יפה ראשון

Comment: [As I mention above](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45057/%d7%a8%d7%90%d7%a9-%d7%95%d7%a8%d7%90%d7%a9%d7%95%d7%9f-%d7%9c%d7%9b%d7%9c-%d7%93%d7%91%d7%a8-%d7%a9%d7%91%d7%a7%d7%93%d7%95%d7%a9%d7%94#comment119291_45057), if this is referring to Kohanim, then likely the version in Moed Katan not Gittin is being referenced, because of the extra word ראש.

Comment: Agree, though there's no reason why it can't be paraphrased from both..

Comment: Zvi and @DoubleAA, This seems plausible. Very interesting though how it became such a popular quote (Google it and you'll find it in all types of *haskamos* and introductory remarks) given that it's not even a direct quote.

Comment: @Zvi It technically can be, just it's pretty weird to say so when you can have it all from one place.

Comment: @DoubleAA Not sure I agree. When something is repeated, it is more likely to become repeated further..

Comment: @Zvi I don't understand your most recent comment. Can you rephrase it? I see two source-texts: one sources phrase A and B and one sources only B. Why would you cite the latter source?

Comment: @DoubleAA I saw you had quoted one, so simply added another similar one. You're certainly right that yours is a major source, likely more relevant than the one I quoted.

Answer (score 3):

[Tehila L'Moshe](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35960&st=&pgnum=35&hilite=)  published in 1563 is the first source I am aware of, although it is used there in a different context.